# How can I disable "Files isn't your default file manager" in Pantheon Files?

Tags: pantheon-files

I do not want to make pantheon-files my default file manager. First time I launched pantheon-files, I get *that* prompt. I clicked 'Ignore' instead of 'Set as Default'. That prompt goes away until the next time I run it. It does not go away as instructed. I wanted to run pantheon-files without being repeatedly asked if I want to set it as default. Thunar is my default file manager.

Answer (score 2):

A quick look at the code indicates that Files does not record whether or not the "Ignore" button was previously pressed so the "Set as Default" option always appears on running if Files is not default. This is, I think, a bug but there is no open report about it on https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files at the moment that I could find. I suggest you raise such a report.  Perhaps a "Do not ask again" checkbox should be added to the dialog.